# Python discord.py bot implement the use of multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, discord, bots

I am creating a discord bot and am wondering how multithreading can be implemented. Basically I have a section of the bot that runs with the `on_ready()` function which contains an infinite loop that checks the content of a link every 60 seconds, and so far everything works fine, the problem is that while doing this it should also be able to respond to commands like `!help` but since the program is executing this infinite loop it does not execute all the rest of the code. Since I know that multithreading requires manual execution of the desired function when starting a thread I don't understand how I can implement it with functions such as `async def help(ctx)` which must be executed in response to a message and which have arguments like ctx or message.

Comment: You should use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks) instead.

Comment: Thanks, it took a while to read all the documentation but it works.